# GitHub: A tag but not a release

Tags: git, github, git-tag

I want to tag a certain commit. When I push the tag, GitHub assumes it's a release, I don't want that.

Is there a way to just push the tag without releasing?

Comment: How you know that «GitHub assumes it's a release»?

Comment: When I push a tag it's added as a release.

Comment: Delete the release. That leaves the tag behind.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

GitHub, by default, <del>creates a "release" point when you push a tag</del> (like you can [see in my project](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/releases)), but that doesn't mean it creates an actual release.

By default, a tag has one deliverable associated to the tag, and that is the compressed sources of the repo.

Creating a release means associating *other* deliverables (executables or other binaries) that you may wish to publish under that tag/release.
But you don't have to add any more files (other then the sources) if you don't want to.

So: by default, **you don't have any release**, only "release placeholders" (one per tag), for you to create a release.

As long as you don't upload a binary to a new release, the tags that you have pushed don't represent a release.

---

**Update**

As of 2017-05-31, Github support has stated it's "not currently possible as all tags will appear in [the release] list" - they said they'd pass it along as a feature request, though.

---

2018-04-17 A "[new request on Github community](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Tag-without-release/m-p/7906)" says it is in the feature request.

---

2021-10-04: a [new public beta of GitHub Releases](https://github.blog/2021-10-04-beta-github-releases-improving-release-experience/) states:

> **Tags no longer show in the Release list view**

[image: releases]

Comment: What if I want only the real releases to appear as a release, like v1.0.0, v1.1.5, etc.. A tag that is only there to tag the commit so it's more understandable shouldn't be a release

Comment: @AlexFerg I have edited the answer: by default, a tag does not represent a release. If you had a release, you could reference it through the releases/latest link (as explained in https://help.github.com/articles/linking-to-releases/). As you can see in my project, that wouldn't work (https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/releases/latest): I don't have any release yet.

Comment: @VonC This no longer appears to be true. All your tags are showing up on both the releases and tags tabs.

Comment: @RossAllan I agree. But those tags (visible in the Releases tab) are release placeholders, not full-fledged releases. You can see an example in https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases

Comment: What's the difference between a release and a release placeholder? Either way, it shows up under the public “releases” tab, zipped sources and all, which is the entire problem. *I don't want a release*.

Comment: @LukeMaurer a release placeholder is a tag for which you don't have uploaded any other artifact yet. If you don't want a release, don't push tags on master.

Comment: So, in other words, the answer is, no, you can't have a tag without a release. And I've tagged two commits that weren't on master, and they're both showing up under Releases. It has nothing to do with what branch the commit was on (which would make no sense anyway, since many *releases* happen from branches).

Comment: @LukeMaurer Interesting. I did not know that. Let me search what I can find. You could make that a question on its own.

Comment: Well, I'd just be asking this exact question again :-)

Comment: @LukeMaurer I suspect GitHub does not consider those tags as actual release, not until you explicitly create one in https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/

Comment: Ah, that might be the issue—they're not actually being listed as releases, they just *look* like it if there aren't any actual releases. UI problem, then.

Comment: @LukeMaurer yes, I would agree: UI issue, a confusing way to present those tags in the release section.

Answer (score 2):

Give our new Releases UI Refresh a look, we changed the default behavior and no longer show tags without releases in the release list

https://github.blog/2021-10-04-beta-github-releases-improving-release-experience/

Comment: Is this new functionality available via the API (octokit)? It seems that `POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/tags` always creates a release and there is no option that I can see to tell it to only create a tag without the release.